# Transform Groovy Object into JSON Stackoverflow

Tags: json, groovy

I am converting some XML into a JSON and I use Groovy's `XmlSlurper` to parse XML, then I construct a Groovy `Map` with the needed structure, then I use and `JsonOutput` or `JsonBuilder` to print that object into a JSON. Here's the code:

```
import groovy.json.*

def X = """
<XML>
<Rules>
        <Rule Alias="" EV="Height" Ht="0" InsuredId="1" Number="" QuestionTypeId="22" ResultType="None" Seq="0" Title="現在の身長・体重" Visible="false" Width="0">身長<Answer Alias="" Sev="0">170<Decision Product="">
                    <UnderwritingDecision Decision="ACC"/>
                </Decision>
                <Rule Alias="" EV="Weight" Ht="0" InsuredId="1" Number="" QuestionTypeId="21" ResultType="None" Seq="15" Visible="false" Width="0">体重<Answer Alias="" Sev="0">100<Decision Product="">
                            <UnderwritingDecision Decision="ACC"/>
                        </Decision>
                        <Rule Alias="NPCL" EV="Age" Ht="0" InsuredId="1" Number="" QuestionTypeId="1" ResultType="None" Seq="16" Title="NPCL" Visible="false" Width="0">年齢<Answer Alias="" Sev="0">34<Decision Product="">
                                    <UnderwritingDecision Decision="ACC"/>
                                </Decision>
                            </Answer>
                        </Rule>
                    </Answer>
                </Rule>
            </Answer>
        </Rule>
        <Rule Alias="" ExtID="ImpairmentTag" Ht="0" InsuredId="1" Number="" QuestionTypeId="9" ResultType="None" Seq="1" Title="1項" Visible="true" Width="0">最近3ヶ月以内に、医師の診察・検査・治療・投薬を受けたことがありますか。<Answer Alias="" Sev="0">いいえ<Decision Product="">
                    <UnderwritingDecision Decision="ACC"/>
                </Decision>
            </Answer>
        </Rule>        
</Rules>
</XML>
"""

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(X)
def nodeText = { it.nodeIterator().next().localText()[0] } 
def createQuestion
createQuestion = { 
    [
        Text: nodeText(it),
        // answer could have other questions could be nested
        Answer: !it.Answer.Rule.isEmpty() ? [ nodeText(it.Answer),  createQuestion(it.Answer.Rule)] : [nodeText(it.Answer)],
        InsuredId: it.'@InsuredId',
        Visible: it.'@Visible',
        CategoryText: it.'@Title',
        FieldTypeId: it.'@QuestionTypeId',
        ExitId: it.'@ExtID',
        Alias: it.'@Alias',
        Number: it.'@Number',
        ResultType: it.'@ResultType'
    ]
}

def v = xml.Rules.Rule.collect(createQuestion)
assert v instanceof List
assert v[0] instanceof Map
assert v[0].Text instanceof String
```

Everything seems to be fine and when I print `v` it has a good structure. However, when I use `JsonOutput.toJson(v)` I get `java.lang.StackOverflowError`. If I use `new JsonBuilder(v)` then I get bunch of lines as follows:

```
groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeIterator(JsonOutput.java:442)
at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeObject(JsonOutput.java:272)
at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeIterator(JsonOutput.java:442)
at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeObject(JsonOutput.java:272)
at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeIterator(JsonOutput.java:442)
```

Is there cyclical structure lurking in the `v` object?

Even stranger thing - if following lines added at the end of the above script

```
println v[0].Answer[1].Answer[1]
println JsonOutput.toJson(v[0].Answer[1].Answer[1])
```

You would get in the console:

```
[Text:??, Answer:[34], InsuredId:1, Visible:false, CategoryText:NPCL, FieldTypeId:1, ExitId:, Alias:NPCL, Number:, ResultType:None]
Caught: java.lang.StackOverflowError
java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

Comment: What version of groovy? It seems that it works with 2.4.0. At least no exception is thrown.

Comment: Groovy Version: 2.4.3 JVM: 1.8.0_45 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Windows 8.1

Comment: @Opal see my update to the question - no exception thrown from the script until you try to get a JSON out of the created object, either via `JsonBuilder` or `JsonOutput` classes

Comment: Dont the nodes returned from `XmlSlurper` have a reference to their parent? Which would make them a cyclic graph. Which would blow the stack

Comment: @tim_yates I think `GPathResult` does have it. I kind of solved the issue by explicitly calling `toString()`, `toInteger()`, `toBoolean()`, etc. But why it was printed into console  without a hitch ? I would like it to work the same way for `JsonOutput`